# SWIFT : Prevent backup files on iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, nsurl

**How do I prevent iCloud backup in my app. For that I tried with NSFileManager.** 
    And
**How to implement addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL in Swift?**

```
I tried with this stuff

extension NSFileManager{
    func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url:NSURL)->Bool{
        var error:NSError?
        let success:Bool = url.setResourceValue(NSNumber.numberWithBool(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error);
        return success;
    }
}
```

But it gives me error : Extra argument error in call

Now for calling the above function...

NSFileManager.defaultManager().addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath());

Comment: As soon as you see `var error:NSError?` you can assume that it's code for Swift 1. You're probably now using Xcode 7, which comes with Swift 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code looks like Swift 1.x syntax. Assuming you're using Swift 2.x, you need to use the native Swift [error-handling syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html). Like this:

```
extension NSFileManager{
    func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url:NSURL) throws {
        try url.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
    }
}
```

At the callsite, you need to handle the error like this:

```
do {
    let url = ... // the URL of the file
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url)
} catch {
    // Handle error here
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 version

```
do {
     var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
      resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
      try url.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
} catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Where does **url** come from? Is it to be put into the **application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ...** method?

Answer (score 1):

```
class DiskHelper {

    /// prevent pack up to iCloud for file.By setting this property to true,
     this file will not be backed up to iCloud.
    ///
    /// - Parameter filePath: prevented iCloud backup filePath.
    func preventiCloudBackupForFile(filePath:String) {
        do {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            try FileManager.default.addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url: url as NSURL)
        } catch {
            // Handle error here
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And add extension for FileManager.

```
extension FileManager{
    func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url:NSURL) throws {
        try url.setResourceValue(true, forKey: URLResourceKey.isExcludedFromBackupKey)
    }
}
```

And can be used like this. e.g: **test.png** file

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("test.png").path
DiskHelper().preventiCloudBackupForFile(filePath: filePath)
```